# how to get all options of select using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to get all options of a multiple select using angularjs, there are selected or not. The options are dynamic. No always the select have the same options.

HtML:

```html
 <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label>Select 1</label>
                <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="origen" name="origen[]">
                    <option>A</option>
                    <option>B</option>
                    <option>C</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2 buttoms-left-right">
                <p>
                    <br />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="goright"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="goleft"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label>Select 2</label>
                <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="destino" name="destino[]" ng-model="formData.tags"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have e jquery that pass data from select 1 to select 2. I need all select 2 options, but using angularjs

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#goright').click(function() { return !jQuery('#origen option:selected').remove().appendTo('#destino'); });
    jQuery('#goleft').click(function() { return !jQuery('#destino option:selected').remove().appendTo('#origen'); });

});
```

And in angularjs I have:

```js
angular.module('formDS', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])

// router configurations

.controller('formDSController', function($scope, $http) {
  
        $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.processForm = function() {
            console.log($scope.formData.tags); //return undefined
        };
        
// other code

    });
```

Comment: Is there some reason you are using jQuery in an angular app?

Comment: no, jquery is in other js file, custom.js. Only use jquery to pass data of select 1 to select 2

Comment: you should get rid of that.

Comment: not use jquery and do everything with angularjs?

Comment: yes, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the option values in your controllers $scope.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qtwRQSvr0SvtQFydqHHH?p=preview)

```
<label>Select 1</label>
        <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="origen" name="origen[]">
            <option ng-repeat="opt in select1">{{opt}}</option>

         </select>
....
<label>Select 2</label>
        <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="destino" name="destino[]" ng-model="select2">
          <option ng-repeat="opt in select1">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.select1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
});
```

Absolutely no reason to use jQuery.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you feel like you need to use jQuery, you just need to learn how to do it in angular.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am rookie in angular

Answer (score 0):

You can specify all options values inside controller. and use `ng-options` directive for displaying it in your select element.

You can get all available options in `$scope.list` in controller only.

See the below example.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('crtl', function($scope) {

  $scope.list = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  $scope.selectedValue = 'A';

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="crtl">
    <select ng-options="item as item for item in list" ng-model="selectedValue"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[ng-options docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)**